# Shader flickering - Three js

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have written a shader to simulate day and night using textures and a shader. It's based using a function to get a vector 3 simulating the position of the sun given an hour. It works fine, except from some flickering that I don't Know what may be causing it.

Here is my code:

```
let shaderInstance = dayNightShader(); // this is the shader instance
let date = new Date().getUTCHours(); // get the current hour in GMT

this.earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32); // create a sphere geometry
this.earthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ // create a shader material
  uniforms: {
    sunDirection: {
      value: getSunDirection(date),
    },
    dayTexture: {
      value: this.textureLoader.load(dayTexture),
    },
    nightTexture: {
      value: this.textureLoader.load(night),
    },
    cloudsTexture: {
      value: this.textureLoader.load(clouds),
    },
  },

  vertexShader: shaderInstance.vertex,
  fragmentShader: shaderInstance.fragment,
});


this.earth = new THREE.Mesh(this.earthGeometry, this.earthMaterial); // create the mesh


this.scene.add(this.earth); // add the mesh to the scene
```

here is my shader dayNightShader:

```
export const dayNightShader = () => {
return {
    vertex: `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vSunDir;
    
    uniform vec3 sunDirection;
    
    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    
        vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
        vSunDir = mat3(viewMatrix) * sunDirection;
    
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
    `,
    fragment: `
    uniform sampler2D dayTexture;
    uniform sampler2D nightTexture;
    uniform sampler2D cloudsTexture;
    
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vSunDir;
    
    void main(void) {
        vec3 dayColor = texture2D(dayTexture, vUv).rgb;
        vec3 nightColor = texture2D(nightTexture, vUv).rgb;
        vec3 cloudsColor = texture2D(cloudsTexture, vUv).rgb;

        float cosineAngleSunToNormal = dot(normalize(vNormal), normalize(vSunDir));
    
        cosineAngleSunToNormal = clamp(cosineAngleSunToNormal * 5.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    
        float mixAmount = cosineAngleSunToNormal * 0.5 + 0.5;
        
        vec3 dayColorWithClouds = mix(dayColor, cloudsColor, 0.2);

        vec3 finalColor = mix(nightColor, dayColorWithClouds, mixAmount);


       
    
        gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor, 1.0);
    }
    `};
};
```

Here is the output

[image]

Here is the glitch effect i get time to time, I dont know what is causing it

[image]

This are the warnings I get

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Note that [`ShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial) automatically injects some standard code. If those standard values aren't necessary to your effect, look into using [`RawShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/RawShaderMaterial) and remember to set a high precision with `precision highp float;` and `precision highp int;`